# Access variables in NextJs

Tags: next.js

I want to use variables in NEXTjs application. For this i did:

1. created file: `.env.local` with:

```css
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASS=mypassword
```

And i want to access this:   `console.log(process.env.DB_HOST, 'local variables')`
 When i do this i get `undefined`. Why it happens, and how to get the variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access to your environment variables on client side and server side, they must be prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOST=localhost
NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_USER=myuser
NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_PASS=mypassword
```

if you are going to use them only on the server side, then your example will work

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASS=mypassword
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nextjs higher than 9.4 you can use next.config.js

Snippet from nextjs documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

To add environment variables to the JavaScript bundle, open next.config.js and add the env config:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: 'my-value',
  },
}
```

Comment: @Asking your comment is irrelevant to this question or answer. please remove it